# Creating an AWS Service Proxy for Elastic Beanstalk | API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-api-gateway

I have an EB environment setup and an ExpressJS application running fine on it. I'm planning to abstract it with AWS API Gateway, such that certain missing features (for example, caching) on my current Beanstalk environment will be automatically filled in by the API Gateway.

Now, I have created an API on API Gateway console, and I'm confused how to create and configure the Service Proxy Execution Role as well as the Managed Policies that needs to be associated. How to generate this resources and create a correct Role ARN, and what ActionName/Path Overrides to use? Following is the integration details.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use AWS Service Proxy to interact with the Elastic Beanstalk ["control plane" API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/api/Welcome.html) .

In this case, to call your ExpressJS backend you would set up an HTTP integration, and use the ELB DNS name for your Elastic Beanstalk application, plus the express route, as the integration URI.

Hope this helps,
Ryan

Comment: This solution means the use of HTTP Proxy, and not an AWS Service Proxy. I'm specifically interested in AWS Service Proxy.

Comment: @SubinSebastian Service proxy is only for the AWS API, not for your custom API. What you are specifically interested in is something that isn't supported and can't be done. The only way to expose your custom API is through HTTP integration.

Comment: @MarkB Ok, the idea is clear now. Infact I have put together a couple of endpoints already. Thanks.

Comment: @SubinSebasian If it has to be an HTTP proxy, then the elastic beanstalk app will be available through two URLs? Or would I put in in a VPC?

Comment: I think I found the answer myself in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37581698/how-to-config-the-api-gateway-for-the-service-deployed-in-private-subnet).